# Xpath pulling number in table but nothing after next span

Tags: html, xpath

Currently i am trying to run an Xpath to get the number "222,904" from the code in the image below. At the moment i am getting the date added aswell.

[image]

Currently i have the below Xpath. This is obviously grabbing everything in the table. I cannot use a long string such as "/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div[2]/" as these pages change dynamically so this Xpath will only work on this one page. Any help would be great i'm braking my head over here. Thanks!

```
//div[@class='video-details-inside']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to reach the number here.

For instance, get the `span` with `class="added-time"` and retrieve the *preceding text sibling*:

```
//div[@class="video-details-inside"]/table//span[@class="added-time"]/preceding-sibling::text()
```

Or, just get the `text()` of the appropriate `td`:

```
//div[@class="video-details-inside"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()
```

Comment: i posted an addition here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618733/python-crawler-not-finding-specific-xpath if you have a free second buddy. Would mean a lot