# Python crawler not finding specific Xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I asked my previous question here:

[Xpath pulling number in table but nothing after next span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612745/xpath-pulling-number-in-table-but-nothing-after-next-span/27612770#27612770)

This worked and i managed to see the number i wanted in a firefox plugin called xpath checker. the results show below.

[image]

so I know i can find this number with this xpath, but when trying to run a python scrpit to find and save the number it says it cannot find it.

```
try:
    views = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='video-details-inside']/table//span[@class='added-time']/preceding-sibling::text()")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print "NO views"
    views = 'n/a'
    pass
```

I no that pass is not best practice but i am just testing this at the moment trying to find the number. I'm wondering if i need to change something on the end of the xpath like .text as the xpath checker normally shows a results a little differently. Like below:

[image]

i needed to use the xpath i gave rather than the one used in the above picture because i only want the number and not the date. You can see part of the source in my previous question.

Thanks in advance! scratching my head here.

Comment: Anyone ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath used in [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) **has to point to an element**, not a text node and not an attribute. This is a critical thing here.

The easiest approach here would be to:

- get the `td`'s text (parent)
- get the `span`'s text (child)
- remove child's text from parent's

Code:

```
span = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='video-details-inside']/table//span[@class='added-time']")
td = span.find_element_by_xpath('..')
views = td.text.replace(span.text, '').strip()
```

Comment: Legend, just so i can learn. What we did here was use the xpath to find the bit we did not want, this was in "span". We then removed that. But the bit i am lost on is span.find_element_by_xpath('..') what is the .. representing.

Comment: @BubblewrapBeast `..` is a way to get an element's parent using `xpath`.